# Verificar se valor informado é numérico e se possui 9 caracteres

Tags: c#, .net

Como posso verificar se um valor é numérico, e apenas numérico (sem ocorrência de pontos, traços, etc), independente da quantidade de caracteres que o número contiver, além de ter **exatamente** 9 caracteres, nem mais, nem menos?

> **Exemplos aceitos:** 111111111, 222222222, 123456789
>
> **Exemplos não aceitos:** 1.000, 3,50, 12345678

[Original do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009017/check-if-input-is-number-and-only-contains-digists-0-9)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível obter essa informação usando a máscara `^\d{9}$` em uma expressão regular, que, além de verificar a quantidade de caracteres (`{9}`), verifica se são numéricos (`\d`):

```
string valor = "123456789";
bool ehValido = Regex.IsMatch(valor, @"^\d{9}$");
```

Também é possível via `LINQ`:

```
string valor = "123456789";
bool ehValido = valor.Length == 9 && valor.All(char.IsDigit);
```

---

Para construção eficiente de expressões regulares, recomendo o site [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/).

Comment: Outro verificador de Regex bem interessante é esse: http://www.regexplained.co.uk/

Comment: @gmsantos gostei pelo fato de ele explicar a regex, porém acho que caberia um campo de dados tb :-)